# Argument Type Observable<User[]> is not assignable to parameter of type User[]

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to adapt the [material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) examples like the following:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import { XService } from './x.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'x-component',
  styleUrls: ['x.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'x.component.html',
})

export class XComponent {

  constructor(private xService: XService) {
  }

  displayedColumns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.xService.getUsers());

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

}
```

The getUsers() looks like this:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class XService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  private userUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/X';

  public getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl);
  }

}
```

The user model looks like this:

```js
export class User {

  c1 : string;
  c2 : string;
  c3 : string;
  c4 : string;
}
```

The above REST API `localhost:8080/X` will result in something like this:

```
[ {
  "c1" : 1,
  "c2" : "I",
  "c3" : 244.0,
  "c4" : 0.0,
}, {
 ...
}
]
```

but unfortunately if I try to build it via:

```
ng build
```

I get the following:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.1) is greater than your local
version (1.6.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Date: 2018-02-26T11:03:55.196Z                                                       
Hash: 7f10a43625c2473d5bc9
Time: 4417ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 303 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 323 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js.map (scripts) 69.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 163 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in src/app/x/x.component.ts(21,45): error TS2345: 
Argument of type 'Observable<User[]>' is not assignable 
to parameter of type 'User[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<User[]>'.
```

Based on the examples I would say it should be working but obviously it does not. The question is: Can someone give a hint/tip where to search or what the problem might be?

**Update:**

After changing the getUsers() into this (By suggestion of axl-code)

```js
public getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl).subscribe((data: any) => {
       return data;
    });
 }
```

I got the following error message during `ng build`:

```
ERROR in src/app/x/x.component.ts(21,45): error TS2345: 
Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'User[]'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
```

Comment: Can you please show me your `User` Model properties?

Comment: You need to subscribe in the component and not the service

Comment: @RameshRajendran updated accordingly.

Comment: @EduardoVargas Can you please explain that a little bit cause I'm a JS beginner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more diving into the problem I found the following solutions:

First the method getUsers in the service looks like this:

```js
public getUsers() : Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.userUrl).map(response => {
        const users = response.json();
        return users.map((user) => new User(user));
    });
}
```

The use model class has been enhanced like this:

```js
  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
```

The component X now looks like this:

```js
export class XComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[] = []

  constructor(private xService: XService) {
  }

  displayedColumns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users); 


  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.xService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(
        (users) => {
          this.users = users;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

By using the above I get it compiled without any error.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your provided code, try it this way

```
export class XComponent {
 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User[]>(); // note that you are just instantiating a 
//MatTableDataSource here. There's no data yet. Add it in the constructor
// Note that in your original code, you are doing this <User> instead of <User[]>
  constructor(private xService: XService) {
   this.xService.getUsers().subscribe ( users => {
             this.dataSource.data = users;
       })
  }

  displayedColumns = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'];

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
}
```

You don't need to change anything in your `getUsers()`. Returning it as `Observable<Users[]>` should work because you are subscribing to it in your XComponent, thus you can get just the "Users[]".

Answer (score 1):

This code is returning an Observable:

```
public getUsers() {
  return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl);
}
```

and here:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.xService.getUsers());
```

you are injecting it. If you want to return the content of the observable try:

```
 public getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl).subscribe((data: any) => {
       return data;
    });
 }
```

Comment: Could be something related with here `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<User>(this.xService.getUsers());` you are casting `MatTableDataSource` to User type `<User>` but from your service call you are returning a User Array?

Comment: If I remove the cast in the above assignment I got the message in my original post...and yes the getUsers() returning an array but in the meantime I've learned that I got back something different...

Answer (score 0):

After your update in your question. please use `map` instead of `subscribe`

```
public getUsers() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl)
    .map((data: any) => {
       data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
    });;
 }
```

import this in your service `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

---

Your component should be

```
 this.xService.getUsers().subscribe(response => {  
                     // do what you want from the response.                     
                    });
```

Comment: This produces: `error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User[]>'.
src/app/x/x.service.ts(20,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Observable'.`

Comment: @khmarbaise import this in your service `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

Comment: Imported Observable..changed to: `ERROR in src/app/x/x.service.ts(16,8): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<User[]>'.`...

Answer (score 0):

the "dataSource" of a MatTable can be a Observable or an Array.  I don't know about Material, but, reading the documentation, I supouse you can write

```
dataSource:MatTableDataSource<User>=this.xService.getUsers();
```

Comment: Changed the error message to this: `ERROR in src/app/x/x.component.ts(21,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<User[]>' is not assignable to type 'MatTableDataSource<User>'.
  Property '_data' is missing in type 'Observable<User[]>'.`